# How to Scroll two ListView as one?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I Have two listviews Side by side but I want to scroll both listviews as one how can i do that?

Tried using OnClickListener but it does not seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

I think best approach is to put each list view inside a LinearLayout and specified width on it. This works to display list views side by side. Careful with listviews filling its parent, the layout don't display as you expect. ListView may bypass the width parameter of the parent.
After that you need to put these LinearLayouts on Scrollview and you need set fillViewport. You can reach detailed info about fillViewport from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android%3AfillViewport)

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ScrollView
     android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
     android:background="#000000"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true" <!-- here -->
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#00FF00"
            android:id="@+id/linear2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
           <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@drawable/settingsMenuBorder"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:id="@+id/linear3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
           <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@drawable/settingsMenuBorder"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```